# Recharts dynamic not rendering after data is changed

Tags: dynamic, charts, line, recharts

I need your help. I'm trying to display different chards depending on which tab you click. See here:

[chart1][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/In82n.png

As you can see it does initially load. But when I click the tab it does not show any charts anymore:

[chart2][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xj3K.png

even when I go back to DATA 1 the graph is now gone:

[chart1again][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCnHu.png

even when I go back to DATA 1 the graph is now gone:
I checked with react developer that chartData is correctly changing and am now out of ideas. I hope that someone can help me.

Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-dynamic-lines-hcrpm?file=/src/charts.js

and code:

```
const buildChartHtml = () => {
    let elements = [];
    if (activeType === 0) {
      elements.push(<XAxis dataKey="day" type="number" tickCount={11} label={CHART_INFO[activeType].xAxis_label} />);
      elements.push(<YAxis type="number" label={CHART_INFO[activeType].yAxis_label} />);
      elements.push(<Line data={chartData} dataKey={CHART_INFO[activeType].dataKey} stroke="#FF3333" dot={false} strokeWidth={2} legendType="square" />);
      elements.push(<Line type="linear" data={testline} dataKey="y" stroke="#0000ce" dot={false} strokeWidth={2} legendType="square" />);
    } else if (activeType === 1) {
      elements.push(<XAxis dataKey="day" type="number" tickCount={11} label={CHART_INFO[activeType].xAxis_label} />);
      elements.push(<YAxis type="number" label={CHART_INFO[activeType].yAxis_label} />);
      elements.push(<Line data={chartData} dataKey={CHART_INFO[activeType].dataKey} stroke="#FF3333" dot={false} strokeWidth={2} legendType="square" />);
      elements.push(<ReferenceLine y="1000" label={{ position: "center", value: "Max Budget" }} />);
    }
    setChartHTML(elements);
  };

  // render onMount
  useEffect(() => {
    //check which type of process is run
    setChartData(buildChartData());
    buildChartHtml();
  }, []);

  // change chartData when activeType is changed
  useEffect(() => {
    //check which type of process is run
    if (activeType === 0 && chartData.length > 1) {
      setChartData(data1);
      buildChartHtml();
    }
    if (activeType === 1) {
      setChartData(data2);
      buildChartHtml();
    }
    // console.log("activeType: " + activ ta))
  }, [activeType]);
```

JSX:

```
    return (
    <div>
      <AntTabs value={value} onChange={handleChangeTabs}>
        {CHART_INFO.map((item, index) => (
          <Tab label={item.name} onClick={() => [setActiveType(item.id), setActiveIndex(index)]} />
        ))}
      </AntTabs>
      <LineChart key={CHART_INFO[activeType].dataKey} width={500} height={300} margin={{ top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5, left: 0 }}>
        <Legend verticalAlign="top" />
        <Tooltip />
        {chartHTML}
      </LineChart>
    </div>
  );>
```